# Python Random Forest Prediction Probabilities Reliability, Overfitting?

Tags: python, random-forest, prediction, overfitting, reliability

TLDR: RF prediction probabilities are not consistent

I have created a calibrated Random Forest Model to predict probabilities for attrition of the workforce, but what I am finding is that probabilities for the same employee changes drastically over the span of a day. So for example, lets say I developed the model yesterday, and employee A has a prediction probability of .007560, I run the same employee today through the model, and it outputs the probability is .684939. The only difference between yesterday's data and today's data for this employee will be things like tenure, which is a minimal difference (i.e., tenure has increased by 1 day or .003 years). So reliability in the model predicting probabilities is not there.

I know what is causing this difference: the slight changes in these tenure variables but I don't know why. I suspect over-fitting? But I followed CV procedures when developing the model (code is below) and accuracy didn't really change between train and test sets.

What makes it more confusing is that if I create a new model today, and predict probabilities on this employee's data from yesterday and today, the results are consistent for both days at 0.007764, which is close to the original .007560. I presume its not exactly the same because there is a slight change in the data for the employee. So why the model can provide consistent probabilities on "past" data, but not on "future" data is beyond me.

I am only giving one example here, but this is happening on a larger scale, hence why it is an issue. So my solution for right now is to develop the model every time I need to update workforce attrition probabilities, but keeping all of the parameters the same. I don't like this approach because for the ML pipeline, id refer to just load the saved model and run the data through it, rather than developing the model and run the data through it. Also, would like to understand what is happening here. Below is my code, the example given here is a calibrated RF model, but same thing is happening with a non-calibrated RF model as well. Thanks!

```
#train model    
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_final, y_vars, test_size=0.5, random_state=20)
#CALIBRATED
rf_unfit1=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=1800, max_features='auto', max_depth=100, min_samples_split=2, min_samples_leaf=1, bootstrap=False)
rf_cv=CalibratedClassifierCV(rf_unfit1,method='sigmoid',cv=3)
rf_cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
filename=r'C:\Users\Downloads\model'
joblib.dump(rf_cv, filename)
#make predictions
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Downloads\test.csv')
rf_cv = joblib.load(open(r'C:\Users\Downloads\model', 'rb'))
final_cv_probs=rf_cv.predict_proba(df)[:,1]
print(final_cv_probs)
```

Below are the prediction probabilities for the same employee. Input variables are Columns A - G. Highlighted columns show input variables with slight changes in variable values as days progress.

[image]

Below is the random grid search I conducted to select my hyperparameters

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_final, y_vars, test_size=0.3, random_state=9)
# Number of trees in random forest
n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 200, stop = 2000, num = 10)]
# Number of features to consider at every split
max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']
# Maximum number of levels in tree
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 110, num = 11)]
max_depth.append(None)
# Minimum number of samples required to split a node
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10]
# Minimum number of samples required at each leaf node
min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 4]
# Method of selecting samples for training each tree
bootstrap = [True, False]
# Create the random grid
random_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
               'max_features': max_features,
               'max_depth': max_depth,
               'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
               'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
               'bootstrap': bootstrap}
rf_dev= RandomForestClassifier(random_state=9)
rf_random=RandomizedSearchCV(estimator= rf_dev, param_distributions=random_grid, n_iter=100, cv=3,verbose=2,random_state=9, n_jobs=-1)
```

Comment: Max depth!  Around 8 gives good results and 20 is considered overkill for many problems.   Why 100?  Num Trees?  Around 150 works for many problems.  What does convergence vs. tree-count look like?  If you don't specify classification then its not actually giving probabilities with its regression.  You need to assure it is being fed binomial data for the logistic models. Why 3 cross-validations and not 5 or 10?

Comment: I did a random grid search to select the hyperparameters. I did not look at convergence, this is something I will look into. If I understand correctly, the output variable is whether a person is termed or not, is this what you mean? Finally, I used 3CV because I was concerned about limited data, I have a total of 10k cases, ~15% is termed vs 85% non termed, so I was concerned about class imbalance. It sounds like I need to re-investigate the hyperparameters

Comment: Also I wasnt sure if the fact that I have random state during model development may have an impact? When ready for production, should the model be re-created without random state?

Comment: You can do 5fold cv with balanced classes.  Let the algo balance the classes and work out the cv.  If there are too few folds then it can reduce the level of insight available.  I distrust your grid-searched parameters.  Consider running with the ones I suggested and tell what the difference is, and to estimate realistic performance.  I use CV and train/test for structural selection, but for production I use all the data. I don't think this is classifying, I think it is regressing, and that means your output might not really be a probability.

Comment: Thanks for the tips,  I will give these a try. But I am not fully understanding why you think this is not classifying? Can you clarify? Thanks!

Comment: One has to be careful.  In R you get classification if your data-type is factor.  You can get regression if it isn't.  Given how the leaf estimate is the average of its members, it isn't always obvious that it is classifying or regressing.  I am not familiar with "sigmoid" in random forests.  Their interpolating function is nearly always the mean for the leaf-members.  Impo RF probabilities, especially without new data or retraining, tend to be mathematically consistent.  With close data, especially in low importance columns, they also tend to be technically consistent.